# center of finite dimensional $C^*$ algebra

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

If $A$ is a finite dimensional $C^*$ algebra,is the center $\mathcal{Z}(A)$ of form $\lambda 1_{A}$,where $\lambda\in \mathbb{C}$?

Comment: Why can't $A$ be commutative with dimension >1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A finite-dimensional C$^*$-algebra is of the form $$A=\bigoplus_{j=1}^n M_{k(j)}(\mathbb C).$$ The centre consists precisely of the operators of the form 
$$
T=\bigoplus_{j=1}^n \lambda_j\,I_{k(j)}. 
$$
It follows that $Z(A)=\mathbb C^n$.